# Trigger second animation keyframe (or move div permanently) with CSS animations?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I've tried searching for a solution to this problem, but haven't found one yet.

What I'm trying to do is simple:

When I click one button, I'd like a box to move 200px to the right with CSS transitions. When I click a second button, I'd like the box to move 200px down *from the position it is currently in.*

I have this basic code here:

HTML

```
<button class="one">First</button>
<button class="two">Second</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.box.transOne {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}

.box.transTwo {
  transform: translateY(200px);
}
```

JS

```
$(".one").click(function() {
  $(".box").toggleClass("transOne");
});

$(".two").click(function() {
  $(".box").toggleClass("transTwo");
})
```

However, when I click on button number two, the box does move 200 down, but it moves diagonally back to the first X axis position while it's going down (I.e. it doesn't stay 200px over on the X axis).

Is there a way I can possibly do this with keyframes? Like triggering a second keyframe with a second button click, etc. Or is there a better way? I'm pretty stumped and can't find any solutions, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER

set the translation X  in class `.transTwo` too

```
.box.transTwo {
  transform: translate(200px 200px);
}
```

EXPLANATION

the `transform` is overriding the others, this is the nature behaviour of the css, just like other property `color`, `background-color`,

The basic rule is the **latest property set** is the strongest, the strongest is at `inline style` unless you implement `!important`